# AllowTransparency alternative for rounded edge forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF project and the main window is required to have rounded corners.  I can do this currently by setting AllowTransparency=True.  This way the white background near the rounded corners becomes transparent.

However, AllowTransparency is slow and buggy.  Particularly there's a [known](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465964/wpf-combobox-dropdown-list-appears-behind-the-form-when-allowstransparency-true) issue where AllowTransparency is badly broken and MS refuses to fix it -- and it affects my customers.  Also the MS suggested hotfix is inconsistent at best, so this is also not an option.

It seems I have two choices: 1) simply turn off AllowTransparency and have a miserably ugly form or 2) find a workaround to have rounded edges without AllowTransparency.

StackO is it possible to have rounded edges with AllowTransparency=False in a WPF project?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the hotfix suggested by microsoft?

Comment: 3) Beat some sense into your clients? Or do they have display areas with round corners?

Comment: @dowhilefor Yes, I've tried the hotfix and it's inconsistent.  It's also not something we want clients to have to do.

Comment: The native way to give windows a shape is through SetWindowsRgn().  WPF doesn't support it at all which is a bit strange, probably to avoid trouble with autoscaling.  You could pinvoke it with help from System.Drawing.Region.GetHrgn().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps ? http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm (still with AllowTransparency )
Or this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomWPFWindow.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library a while ago that does this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell.

It exposes a WindowChrome attached property for Window that gets rid of the standard window chrome, and then if you specify that you don't want a glass frame then you can specify a CornerRadius property to round whichever of the corners you want.  There's a sample project included in the download that shows how the different properties work.

The library is implemented by handling WM_NCCALCSIZE (similar to what Office does to customize the chrome), rather than using layered windows, which is how Window.AllowsTransparency is done.

The link is to a slightly old version of the library, but most of the bugs that I fixed since then I think won't affect you since it sounds like you're not using glass.

Comment: There is a newer version of the Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll in Microsoft Ribbon for WPF.

See this thread: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=4337

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clip the round corners out you could override OnPaint in the form and create a path (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath) with the required shape of your window and assign that path to your form's Region property.  This is a bit clunky but it may do what you want.  For example, for uniform curved corners you could do (vb, not C#, sorry):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Dim r As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle
        Dim w As Integer = 50 'width of curvature
        Dim h As Integer = 50 'heigth of curvature

        Dim gp As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
        gp.StartFigure()
        gp.AddArc(r.Right - w, r.Top, w, h, 270, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.Right - w, r.Bottom - h, w, h, 0, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.Left, r.Bottom - h, w, h, 90, 90)
        gp.AddArc(r.Left, r.Top, w, h, 180, 90)
        gp.CloseFigure()

        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gp)

        Me.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(gp)

    End Sub
```