# WPF : Transparency of Window eliminated by semi-transparent brush of a contained object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a `Window` with the property `AllowsTransparency` set to **true**, and with the `Background` property set to a semi-transparent color, the code :

```
<Window x:Class="InstantSnip.MainView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
            AllowsTransparency="True" 
            WindowStyle="None" 
            ResizeMode="NoResize" 
            Topmost="True" 
            Width="180" Height="80" 
            Background="#7FFFFFFF" >

        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                CornerRadius="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource NewSnipButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ReTrySnippingButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
</Window>
```

This is how it looks like :

[image]

Now, I want to give the `Background="#7FFFFFFF"` to the `LayoutRoot` Border instead of the Window so that the color can fit exactly and only inside the Border's boder, which is not the case when the `Background="#7FFFFFFF"` is a property of the Window as you can see here :

[image]

And hence, and with no big changes, the code will simply be as follows :

```
<Window x:Class="InstantSnip.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        Topmost="True" 
        Width="180" 
        Height="80">

    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
            BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" 
            Background="#7FFFFFFF" 
            BorderThickness="1" 
            CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource NewSnipButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ReTrySnippingButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" Margin="5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

But what I get is this :

[image]

My first question is, why ?

My second question is, can you suggest a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Background` to `Transparent` in your `Window` that will do the trick

eg

```
<Window x:Class="InstantSnip.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        Topmost="True" 
        Width="180" 
        Height="80"
        Background="Transparent" >
```

result

[image: result]

I don't have your styles so the button appears normal button

**Edit**

Explanation for your first question

As the default `Background` of a `Window` is usually `White` inherited from [SystemColors.WindowColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.windowcolor). So unless you set any color which is fully or partially transparent, `AllowsTransparency` will not be able to compose transparency on it's own.

as any child control is rendered on window first then the whole window is composed to the background. So in short no matter what transparent color you set on your child controls it will be composed on a white background leading to no transparency.

so set `Transparent` on `Window` and then you can choose to have rounded corner border etc with desired transparent color.

**From:** [Transparent Windows in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx)

WPF can obviously render transparent elements within its own window, but it also supports rendering the entire window with per-pixel transparency. This feature comes with a few issues.

Comment: Perfect,Thx for the typo and the explanation, I got it all working and understood now.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you moved the Background property from the window to the border control. My guess, and it's only a guess, is that UserControls don't support transparent backgrounds.

This sounds similar to [AllowTransparency alternative for rounded edge forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790589/allowtransparency-alternative-for-rounded-edge-forms). Perhaps its accepted answer will work for you.

Comment: There's no UserControl in my code, there are a window and Border, Grid and buttons, and all of them support transparency, what are you pointing to, still I'll read the links you suggested

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thinking Border was a UserControl. Perhaps it doesn't support transparency using the alpha channel. I think it has an Opacity property. Does setting that to 0.5 give you what you want?