# Make a component transparent in WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, transparency

I'm brand new in windows phone 8.1 and there were heaps changes in windows phone 8.1 compare to windows phone 8. How can I make a component, say Button, Grid, Tile to be transparent exactly like in the picture from the link below. Please Help!!!!!

[WPF : Transparency of Window eliminated by semi-transparent brush of a contained object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794435/wpf-transparency-of-window-eliminated-by-semi-transparent-brush-of-a-contained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make transparency use the alpha in the background not the opacity, Background="#7FFFFFFF" make the 7F lower to  make it more transparent.

If you want the control with transparency and the same border do the following

```
<Border VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Background="#7FFFFFFF" 
            BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </Grid>
</Border>
```

That is generic for any control, but the button has that properties ready but the CornerRadius, so you can use this XAML:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Background="#7FFFFFFF" 
            BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" >
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </Grid>
</Button>
```

And in case you need the corner radius, you need to right click in the button in the designer, edit the template, create a copy and at the end of the template you have:

```
<Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Border>
```

Change there the radius and everything you need.

Comment: I'm using Listview Control. How can I make the Tiles of the Listview to be transparent but not the text. Cuz I set the opacity to 0.3 and the text is also getting blur.

Comment: To make transparency use the alpha in the background not the opacity, Background="#7FFFFFFF" make the 7F lower to make it more transparent.

Comment: By the way how can I do the same thing for Bottom App Bar?

Comment: In this case changing the opacity does not affect to the controls inside, and if you add some opacity the page gets the full size, so take care of this, it's 48px if I remember well

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing for Flyout Stackpanel but it doesn't work. Any idea?